# How to analyze the code from GitHub repository in sonarqube

Tags: github, sonarqube, sonarlint

How to analyze the code from GitHub repository in sonarqube ?

Please suggest and provide the step by step procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Github is a source repository.  It's sort of like a database.  It just sits there and waits for requests.  In a way it doesn't really "do" anything.  If you need to "do" something with it, like build executables or run SonarQube scans on the code, you have to utilize other resources like Travis or Jenkins to run scripts that will build the executables and run SonarQube scans.

Depending on what programming language your code is using, there are different tools for managing the running of the SonarQube scan.  If your code is Java and you're using Maven, you can use the "sonar:sonar" goal, along with setting several properties, to run the scan.  If you have something else, then use the "sonar-scanner" tool, also with setting several properties.

Note that the SonarQube scan is almost always run as part of the build process, because the SonarQube scan needs some of the artifacts produced by the build to produce its analysis reports.  For instance, it is typical to run the SonarQube scan after the unit tests are run, so SonarQube can see the resulting code coverage.

At this point, I can't really give you a step-by-step procedure. There are many pieces you're going to have to assemble, and that will require some choices on your part.

Answer (score 0):

Github provides git repositories, but it also provides processing services like Github Actions. You can use them to 'make stuff happen' - with some abstraction it is something like an integrated Jenkins or Travis.

So either you run your own system to clone the git repository and then scan it locally, or you use Github Actions.

See

- https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions
- https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube-scan-action